# Show block on category page

Tags: layout, xml, blocks, phtml

I have this layout for my products/category view:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page ">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category_title') ?>
        <div class="main-container row collapse col2-left-layout">
            <div class="main large-12 columns">
                <?php // This left_first block will display above the main content on smaller viewports ?>
                <?php if ($_leftContent = $this->getChildHtml('left_first')): ?>
                <div class="col-left sidebar col-left-first large-2 medium-3 columns"><?php echo $_leftContent;   ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="col-main large-10 medium-9 columns">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-left sidebar" style="background:green;"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_before') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_cookie_notice') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

In `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category_title') ?>` I want to display my .phtml file that I've created:

```
<?php
    $_helper    = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
    $_category  = Mage::registry('current_category');
    if ( ! $_category) {
        $categoryId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($categoryId);
    }
    $_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl();
?>
<?php
    if (!$_imgUrl){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $(".top-container").addClass("no-image");
});
</script>
<?php
    }
?>
<div class="category-header-container">
    <div class="bgback" style="background:#F7F6F4;">
        <div class="container row" style="<?php if($_imgUrl): ?>background-image: url(<?php echo $_imgUrl; ?>);<?php endif; ?>">
            <div class="table-container">
                <div class="category-top-title">
                    <h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="left-area breadcrumbs-holder">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml("breadcrumbs"); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="zn_header_bottom_style"></div>
```

But, I can't achieve that... I don't know what I'm mising...

I've created this entry in my `local.xml` inside of `<catalog_category_view>` tag

```
<reference name="category_title">
    <block type="core/template" name="page.header" template="page/html/page_header.phtml">
        <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
    </block>
</reference>
```

What I'm missing? Do I need to modify page.xml or catalog.xml ? If yes, could you give me an example what should be added there to make it work?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

You need to  add `category_title` phtml  but don't define at `layout xml file` so,you need this `block at page.xml`.
As per your code you have add `the block reference of root`

So need  to add the `below xml code at page.xml`

```
<reference name="root">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="category_title" as="category_title" translate="label">
    </block>
</reference>
```

`core/text_list` not work then use `core/template`

Comment: Still nothing, so this <block type="core/text_list" name="category-title" as="category-title"></block> has to be in page xml, then this <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category-title') ?> on mylayout.phtml and then this     <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="category-title" as="category-title" translate="label" template="page/html/page_header.phtml"></block>
    </reference> in local.xml ? Is that correct?

Comment: please set template for this block  at page.xml with page.xml  and  the code <reference name="root"> <block type="core/text_list" name="category-title" as="category-title" translate="label" template="page/html/page_header.phtml"></block> </reference>  not need

Comment: I appologize, but I'm having a hard time to understand what you're saying. So there should be on page.xml inside of <default> this: <block type="core/text_list" name="category-title" as="category-title"></block> and then this: <reference name="root"> <block type="core/text_list" name="category-title" as="category-title" translate="label" template="page/html/page_header.phtml"></block> </reference> ? Both of them has to be in <default>?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't work, please confirm, that I've understood you correctly: now I have in my page.xml inside of <default></default> this line:         <referencename="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="category-title" as="category-title" translate="label" template="page/html/page_header.phtml">
            </block>
        </reference> and then on the golulo-cat.phtml (this is my layout.phtml this line: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category-title') ?> and it doesn't shop up.

Comment: where you have add this code: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('category-title') ?>

Comment: in the layout.phtml, I have a custom one based on 2-columns-left.phtml in directory: default/template/page

Comment: what is layout of your category page?

Comment: basically the same as 2columns-left.phtml with some minor changes.

Comment: ok, it's now showing up. Changed as you suggested: text_list to template.

Comment: have you change class block type core/text_list to core/template?

Comment: but breadcrumbs are missing?

Comment: remove <block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>

Comment: is it works?please tell me?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, from where I should remove the breadcrumbs? Also I'm having an issue, that this field appear on search result's, as I use the same layout there. How can I specify for it to be visible only on the Category view?